# Apache Nifi PutDistributedMapCache lifespan

Tags: apache-nifi

Can anyone guide me about the PutDistributedMapCache , I wanted to know if we have cached a attribute or a value , What would be the lifespan for that attribute or value ?
Till when it would be cached ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processor `PutDistributedMapCache` doesn't itself define the Time-To-Live (TTL) for cached entries, that is up to the `Distributed Cache Service` you set in that processor. Some implementations have a TTL property (such as the Hazelcast, Redis, and Cassandra implementation) and some don't (such as the in-memory DistributedMapCacheClientService and the Couchbase and HBase implementations). The ones that don't allow for the user setting the TTL either have a default or they never expire.